In React Native why the hook re-render when run useState function inside the hook
const useLocationPicker = ({ 
    handleSelect
}) => {

const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
const [query, setQuery] = useState('')


const handleOpenLocationPicker = async () => {
setModalVisible(true)
}

const handleCloseLocationPicker = async () => {
setModalVisible(false)
setQuery('');
}

const handleSearch = async (text) => {
  setQuery(text);
}

const handleGetCurrentLocation = async () => {
const CURRENT_LOCATION = await getCurrentLocation()
handleSelect(CURRENT_LOCATION)
handleCloseLocationPicker();
};

const handleSelectLocation = async (data) => {
handleSelect(data)
handleCloseLocationPicker();
};

const LocationPickerModal = () => (
    <Modal
      animationType="slide"
      presentationStyle='formSheet'
      visible={modalVisible}
      onRequestClose={handleCloseLocationPicker}
    >
        
        <View>
            <TextInput
            onChangeText={(text)=>handleSearch(text)}
            placeholder='Search'
            style={styles.searchBox}
            />
        </View>

        {query.length===0?
          <>
            <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.item}
            onPress={handleGetCurrentLocation}
            >
            <View
            style={styles.itemIcon}
            />
            <Text style={styles.p1}>Your location</Text> 
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <History
            handleSelect={handleSelectLocation}
            />
          </>
          :
          <Predictions
          query={query}
          handleSelect={handleSelectLocation}
          />
          }

    </Modal>
  );

return { 
    handleOpenLocationPicker, 
    LocationPickerModal
};
}

export default useLocationPicker


i create this location picker. i want use it in more than one screens that is the reason i want to create a common component. i try this way above. Working when handleSelect, but when try to setQuery not working correct, for a reason modal close and re-open, is like when run any function in hook auto re render. How can fix this?

i fix this with useMemo
const LocationPickerModal = useMemo(() => { return ( <Modal>...Modal</Modal> )}, [modalVisible, query]);
